# Alternating table colors not reset when longtable spans multiple pages

Tags: longtable, rowcolor

I've searched and found similar issues, but nothing that really worked in my application.  I'm attempting to generate a pricebook with images/specs in a caption of a long table.  That's all working great, but I would also like to apply alternating colors.  Works fine, unless I have a longtable that spills over into the next page.  It does not seem to reset the row count number, so it just applies the next background color as though it were directly below the original table.  It should be white for first rows after the header, but the second table has a gray background.  Here is what should be a working example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[letterpaper, lmargin=.5in, rmargin=.5in, tmargin=1in, bmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand\footrule{\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\hrule width \hsize height 2pt \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize
\end{minipage}\par}%

\lfoot{\today}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\cfoot{}
\rhead{}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\renewcommand {\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand {\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\captionsetup{labelsep=space,singlelinecheck=off,labelformat=empty,labelfont=bf}
%
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
%

\newif\ifimportant\importanttrue

\AddEverypageHook{
\global\importanttrue
}

\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{E5E4E2}
\definecolor{light-cyan}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.80}
\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.95}

\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{sf}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=black}

\begin{document}

\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}}

\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Clearance}
\markboth{Clearance}{}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\rowcolors{1}{light-cyan}{light-gray}
\begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{3.75in}p{.875in}}
\caption{
\ifimportant
\begin{minipage}[l]{0.3\textwidth}
\protect\includegraphics[width=1.875in,height=1.875in,keepaspectratio,left]{example-image}
\newline
\newline
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[r]{0.7\textwidth}
\hspace{\fill}
\end{minipage}
\global\importantfalse
\fi
\textbf{Faucets}
}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Faucets}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Gray}
Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{
\begin{minipage}[l]{0.3\textwidth}
\protect\includegraphics[width=1.875in,height=2in,keepaspectratio,left]{example-image}
\newline
\newline
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[r]{0.7\textwidth}
\hspace{\fill}
\end{minipage}
\textbf{Faucets}
}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Gray}
Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
\hline
\endhead
387961 &  & K10577-4-2BZ BANCROFT WS LAV FCT & \$613.15 ea\\\hline
279697 & 10577-4P-BN & K10577-4P-BN BANCRFT W/S FCT & \$659.70 ea\\\hline
97397 &  & K11395-S 42 TRANS GRAB BAR ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASD & \$114.95 ea\\\hline
387968 &  & K11414-2BZ BANCROFT ROBE HOOK & \$42.40 ea\\\hline
37042 & 11581-CP & K11581-CP LOURE 24 TOWEL BAR & \$152.05 ea\\\hline
37906 & 11585-CP & K11585-CP LOURE ROBE HOOK & \$133.05 ea\\\hline
353981 & 11881-S & K11881-S MARGAUX 12 GRAB BAR & \$202.05 ea\\\hline
275281 & 11892-S & K11892-S PURIST 18 GRAB BAR & \$183.50 ea\\\hline
252952 & 12150-G & K12150-G 18IN BRU CHR TWL BAR & \$81.40 ea\\\hline
57743 & 12172-BN & K12172-BN FAIRFAX W/ SPRAY & \$383.45 ea\\\hline
2175 & 12177-G & K12177-G FAIRFAX P/O KIT FCT & \$413.55 ea\\\hline
256039 & 12182-BRZ & K12182-BRZ FAIRFAX S/H LAV FCT & \$353.00 ea\\\hline
100380 & 12183-BRZ & K12183-BRZ FAIRFAX SINK FCT & \$542.05 ea\\\hline
138661 & 128-SN & K128-SN ANTIQUE RISER TUBE(PR) & \$496.85 ea\\\hline
324289 & 13132-4B-BN & K13132-4B-BN PINSTRIPE LAV FCT & \$1353.70 ea\\\hline
15233 & 13864-CP & K13864-CP C/BRS SINK STRAINER & \$141.30 ea\\\hline
122632 & 15182-F-G & K15182-F-G LEVER HNDL LAV FCT & \$207.80 ea\\\hline
11301 & 16010-2-CP & K16010-2-CP TRITON SQR HDLS & \$68.60 ea\\\hline
51577 & 16012-2-CP & K16012-2-CP TRITON STD HANDLES & \$127.40 ea\\\hline
284047 & 16012-4-CP & K16012-4-CP TRITON LVR HANDLE & \$120.60 ea\\\hline
80275 & 16140-BV & K16140-BV TOWEL RING & \$358.40 ea\\\hline
92315 & 16141-BV & K16141-BV TOILET TISSUE HOLDER & \$354.85 ea\\\hline
88279 & 16146-BV & K16146-BV ROBE HOOK & \$203.25 ea\\\hline
84369 & 16150-BV & K16150-BV 24IN TOWEL BAR & \$432.45 ea\\\hline
286726 & 16252-CP & K16252-CP MARGAUX 30 TWL BAR & \$190.60 ea\\\hline
89795 & 16256-BN & K16256-BN MARGAUX ROBE HK & \$123.95 ea\\\hline
255048 & 303-K-NA & K303-K-NA 3-HNDL VALVE SYSTEM & \$165.80 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, if I compile your document on my machine, the first row on the second page is white, and that's what you seem to want? (BTW, I do not know if it makes too much sense to specify width, height and `keepaspectratio` in includegraphics.)

Comment: like normal page breaking, longtable page breaking happens asynchronously the table rows, including background colour, are set before tex has decided where to split the pages.

Comment: @David Carlisle: So is there a way around that?  Longtable is a bit of a strange beast.

Comment: oi, I take it you know the author of that software:-)

Comment: lol, great package that has made things much easier, just requires some workarounds that are beyond my skillz.  ;)

Comment: unrelated, but report hasn't got an 8pt option and, and setting both LTleft and LTright to 0pt is making tex complain about underfull boxes

Comment: Fixed the 8pt.  What would be a better value for LTleft/LTright to eliminate the underfull boxes but still make longtable full-width?

Comment: you could make the fixed width columns add up to \textwidth (remembering that each column has 12pt (2\tabcolsep) padding in addition to the specified width (or use \extracolsep to add stretchy space between the columns). For your main question short answer is no it's not easy to do reset the colour automatically but once the document is stable and no more edits you can always reset the row counter (and so colour) by hand in the first row of each page

Comment: Gotcha.  Challenge is, the sheet is dynamically generated based on what the end-user wants (potentially over 20k items).  I can probably accept that the first row color may be inconsistent, or I can just omit the background color.  Thank you for the feedback on the LTleft/right.

Comment: don't think of the first row colour as being inconsistent (that would imply a bug) think of it as tex does: it is not a sequence of tables each with a "first row" it is a single table, with odd and even rows coloured differently, with that table spread over multiple pages. So, documented feature not bug.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle,CGRemakes Has anyone here managed to make progress on this question? I have asked a similar one (linked) and am hoping that it can be done.